# Counting certain permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $S = (\pi(1), \pi(2),\cdots,\pi(n))$ be a permutation of $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ such that $S$ does not contain the pattern $\pi(i)<\pi(j)<\pi(k)$ for any $i<j<k$.

For example, the permutation $(1,4,3,2,5)$ is not allowed since it contains $1,\cdots,2,5$ in that order.

How do we count the number of such permutations (of $n$ numbers)?

I know how to count permutations that forbid the pattern $\pi(k)<\pi(i)<\pi(j)$ for any $i<j<k$, namely they are counted by the Catalan Number $C_n$. But the $\pi(i)<\pi(j)<\pi(k)$ pattern doesn't seem to yield to such a method. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: The linked question is about $321$-avoiding permutations, but these correspond to $123$-avoiding permutations by inversion. It turns out that there are in fact equally many permutations avoiding any pattern of length $3$. (See Wikipedia on [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics) and on [permutation patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_pattern).)

Comment: See also [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.1325.pdf) and Exercises $2$ through $5$ in Section $2.2.1$ of [Volume $1$ of Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/The%20Art%20of%20Computer%20Programming%20(vol.%201_%20Fundamental%20Algorithms)%20(3rd%20ed.)%20%5BKnuth%201997-07-17%5D.pdf).

Comment: @joriki Thanks!